# How to convert 1D arrays into 2D arrays for the plot_surf() function to work correctly in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

The original code written in the following format was running without any error yet it did not produce the desired 2d-function plot/surface. In fact, I was getting the 3d space with all the titles and labels but without actual 2d plot. I have tried to check the output by print() function at each step. It seems that the code produces correctly the z array but surf() is not responding accordingly. So, the question should have been instead "What method is missing in the code so that Surface() is not responding accordingly?"

```
import sys


import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('SVG')
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

import numpy as np

from numpy import array as ar


import random
from scipy import linspace, meshgrid, arange, empty, concatenate, newaxis, shape

import math

fig =pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

N = 10000
data1 = [random.random() for i in range(N)]
x1 = ar(data1)
data2 = [random.random() for i in range(N)]
x2 = ar(data2)


a = 2.000000
y1 = np.sqrt((-1.000000) * a * np.log(x1)) * np.cos(2 * math.pi * x2)
y2 = np.sqrt((-1.000000) * a * np.log(x1)) * np.sin(2 * math.pi * x2)
gaussian1 = math.pow(2 * math.pi, (-1.000000 / a)) * np.exp((-1.000000 / a) * y1**a)
gaussian2 = math.pow(2 * math.pi, (-1.000000 / a)) * np.exp((-1.000000 / a) * y2**a)
z = gaussian1 * gaussian2

    surf = ax.plot_surface(x1, x2, z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=1.0)
fig.colorbar(surf)

title = ax.set_title("Probability Distribution Function")
title.set_y(1.01)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(10))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(10))

fig.set_tight_layout(True)
fig.savefig('Gaussian.svg')
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: also this line is not necessary i think `ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')` because you defined ax at the top

Comment: Hi. Dear IanAuld, thanks for the recommendation. I am trying to edit the code. And, user2255757, I just noticed that there is a redundancy in that line. I tried either one by itself. The problem still persists.

Comment: Are the axis of the plot in the range you expect them to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your arrays. From the documentation to [`plot_surface`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots):

> Axes3D.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, *args, **kwargs)
>
> X, Y, Z:  Data values as 2D arrays

your `X, Y, Z` are 1D arrays, so won't work properly.

You could make `x1` and `x2` the correct format using `np.meshgrid`:

```
x1, x2 = np.meshgrid(x1,x2)
```

Then generate `z` using these 2D arrays.

However, note that creating a 10000x10000 surface may use a lot of memory!

Comment: Hi dear Tom, thanks for your quick help. It was indeed the case. Sincerely,

Comment: Do you have some workaround to avoid using such large amount of memory? Indeed it is very slow to produce the plot.

Comment: @tom How to generate z using x1 and x2 ?